# What to do when you can't compare two objects?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am very new to programming and have been learning on my own for a month or so. I haven't gotten very far and I hit a stumbling block at my latest attempt to write a simple program that will get the current month and date, check if the current month and date match an element in an array, and if so log a string to the console.

The error I get is just "undefined object".  I guess what I am doing wrong is trying to compare two objects? Is there any way to convert what I want to compare to values so a boolean operator can be used? Code below.

```
var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();
var currentDay = new Date().getDate();

var royalMonths = months: [ 2, 11, 6, 8, 9, 1, 5, 7 ]
var royalDays = [ 6, 14, 10, 15, 21, 9, 2, 22 ]
var members = [
  "Queen Elizabeth",
  "Prince Charles",
  "Prince Philip",
  "Princess Anne",
  "Prince William",
  "Prince Harry",
  "Princess Kate"
]

if (currentMonth in royalMonths && currentDay in royalDays) {
  console.log("It's a royal birthday!");
} else {
  console.log("It's a royal unbirthday.");
}
```

Comment: I think you got your methods mixed with operands. if is a condition and uses  > < == === !=, etc. `in` as in `for(x in X)` is used to iterate (loop) through an object. Anyways you need to define those objects `royal*` ex. `var royalMonths = {currentDay: 'Friday`}`.

Comment: I suggested an edit to your code sample but I think you must've updated it while I was still submitting, as it now contains a bunch of extra code! Feel free to decline it :)

Answer (score 0):

"Undefined object" isn't a complete error message, and the code you show isn't complete either which makes it a bit tricky to help. Here's an example using `Array.find` to check for a value in an array:

```js
const dates = [ 1, 2, 3, 31, 29 ]
const myDate = 3
if (dates.find(d => d === myDate)) {
  console.log('Found it!')
} else {
  console.log('Nope.')
}

// Or:
if (dates.includes(myDate)) {
  console.log('Yup, it includes it.')
}
```

It does depend a bit what's in the array. Simple values are slightly easier, so get those working first and then move to more complex objects. If you need more detail, try to post a more complete example (I suggest using the snippet feature as I have done here) so people can see what you're attempting more clearly.

Edit: now that I can see your complete example, let's look at some of the problems. Note that if you look at the line numbers in your error messages, they will often give you a pretty strong clue as to where the problem is.

```js
var royalMonths = months: [2, 11, 6, 8, 9, 1, 5, 7]
```

When run, this causes the error:

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"
```

This is because you're trying to use syntax we usually find in object literals without using the curly braces that signify an object literal. For example, this would be correct syntax:

```
var royalMonths = {
  months: [ 1, 2 ]
}
```

You don't actually need an object for your purposes, however.

Finally, although this is valid JavaScript (in ES6 and later, I believe) it doesn't do what you think:

```
if (currentMonth in royalMonths) {
```

This will examine property names of the object, which for arrays is their indices. So if `currentMonth` was 2 and `royalMonths` had three or more elements, it would evaluate `true`. You should try using `Array.includes` as I demonstrated above, you'll have more luck.